# Float 2 elements next to eachother

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to position two  elements within an li list next to eachother on the right side to get the result:
*Some text.................A...B*
 Unfortunatelly the ordering drives me crazy.

Here's the html code:

```
<ul class="list">
<li>some text 
     <small class="a">A</small>
     <small class="b">B</small>
</li>
</ul>
```

With the following CSS code I was able to get the small-elements on the right side next to each other, but the result is that i see on the right side B next to A!

```
.list li{
    background-color:#282828;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left:5px;
 }


 .list small.a {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
 }


 .list small.b {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
 }
```

So, I aim to have:
some tex.....................A...B

but for instance it looks like:
some text....................B...A

**See example here** --> http://jsfiddle.net/LKVdE/

Thanks upfront for any tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/LKVdE/1/

**CSS**

```
.list small.a {
    background-color: #000000;
    display: inline;
}
.list small.b {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: inline;
}
.list li span{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
     <li>Brennwert kJ / kcal
         <span>
            <small class="a">1109kJ / 261kcal</small>
            <small class="b">455kJ / 107kcal</small>
         </span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Why does this happen, because first style is applied to a which moves it to to the right, whatever next appears in the markup must now follow a from the right that's why you see **BA** instead of **AB**

Markup changes: Include the text inside a span and add `float:left` to it

```
<ul class="list">
<li><span class="text">some text</span>
     <small class="a">A</small>
     <small class="b">B</small>
</li>
</ul>
```

Css changes, remove `float:right` from a and b and add `float:left` to text

```
    .text{float:left;}
    .list small.a {
        display:inline;
     }  
     .list small.b {
        display:inline;
     }
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKVdE/8/

Answer (score 1):

A and B should be put in a right floating container:

```
        .list small.a {
            display:inline;
        }


        .list small.b {
            display:inline;
        }

        .floatright {
            float:right;
        }
```

And

```
        <li>some text
            <div class="floatright">
                <small class="a">A</small>
                <small class="b">B</small>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! Great tip! I tried it and it worked out perfectly :)